# element disappears when position set to absolute?

Tags: html, css, css-position

simple project, but a beginner at programming, so struggling. I am trying to set a couple of buttons to create a slider to change pictures. My problem is that when I set the position attribute to absolute in the div that contains the buttons, the div element that contains the buttons disappears.

So this is a screenshot of my page with position set to relative:

```
.buttons {
          cursor: pointer;
          position: relative;
}
```

[image]

and this is with it set to absolute:

```
.buttons {
          cursor: pointer;
          position: absolute;
}
```

[image]

And here is the code

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

    <head>

        <meta charset="UTF-8">

        <title>Photography</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript2b.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript2.js"></script>


    </head>

    <body>

    <div id="header">
    </div>

      <div id="container">

        <div id="imagewrap">
          <img src="Images/01Folder/Image.jpg" height="500px" id="front" />

          <div id="previous" class="buttons" onclick="change(-1);">
          </div>

          <div id="next" class="buttons" onclick="change(1);">
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>


    <div id="footer">
    </div>

    </body>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript2.js"></script>

</html>
```

css

```
html, body {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            height: 100vh;
    }

#header {
    position: relative;
    height: 10%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: lightgray;
}

#footer {
    position: relative;
    height: 10%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: lightgray;
    display: block;
}

#container {
    height: 80%;
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: white;
    min-height: 580px;
    text-align: center;
}

#imagewrap{
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #818181;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 5;
    display: inline-block;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.buttons {
          cursor: pointer;
          position: relative;
}

#previous {
            background-image: url(Images/carremoins.png);
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: center center;
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
        }

#next {
            background-image: url(Images/carreplus.png);
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            background-position: center center;
}
```

I would like the buttons to be on the picture, not below it, but can't understand why they disappear. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Add some offset e.g. `left:0;` and `top:0;` values to the absolute element.

Comment: Hey @Paul, any luck with this? Was it a case of z-index, in the end?

Comment: the solution was to add some offset like Pangloss suggested. I am not too sure why though

Comment: Yeah, that defines where the element will be positioned relative to the top-left corner of the parent element. Beware that if this width changes (for different devices, say) then also the relative position towards the image will change.

Answer (score 2):

Your container, `#imagewrap`, has `overflow: hidden`.  When you make its children `position: absolute`, you remove them from calculations determining the size of the parent element, so the parent is no longer large enough to display the children.  That means they are overflow, which you have specified should be hidden.

You can solve this problem in several ways, depending on your needs.  You can allow overflow, reposition the children so they are inside of the parent, and/or increase the size of the parent such that it encompasses its children.  Any or all will make the children visible.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the z-index on the buttons to a value larger than that of the image (5).

```
.buttons {
   cursor: pointer;
   position: relative;
   z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by this, @ata?